# Kalman Filter - Fusion of two equal sensors

Tags: python, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I'm interested in implementing a Kalman Filter in Python. First, I have programmed a very simple version of a K-Filter - only one state (Position in Y-Direction). 
My State transition Matrix looks like:

```
X <- X + v * t
```

with v and t are constants.

I simulate the measurement with a simple linear function

```
y = mx + b
```

and add noise to it:

```
y1 = np.random.normal(y, sigma, Nsamples).
```

It works pretty well, I can redefine R and Q to change the measurement and process noise value (Until now, it isn't a matrix).

Now I have an idea...

What happens if I would have a second measurement?

```
    y2 = np.random.normal(y, sigma2, Nsamples)
```

How could I handle it? Shall I prefilter measurement like :

```
(y1 + y2) / 2
```

or is there a more suitable method/solution which involves the kalman filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to handle fusion of multiple sensor measurements using Kalman Filter. A way to do it would be sequentially updating the Kalman Filter with new measurements.

See the slides by sensor fusion pioneer Hugh Durrant-Whyte found in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/248671) for quite a few ways how to fuse sensor data.